# FindOneAndUpdateAsync not using CustomSerilaizer in MongoDB C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, driver

We've written a custom serializer for MongoDB to serialize a [custom `Id` type](https://github.com/jamescrosswell/MongoTests/blob/master/Core/Id.cs). The serializer writes our custom Id out to Mongo as an `ObjectId`, but represents it in C# as our custom `Id`. The idea here is that we could have some  domain classes that are database agnostic (in case we ever need to store these in something other than MongoDb).

This works well for simple insert or replace operations... but doesn't appear to be used by `FindOneAndUpdateAsync` operations. When performing a `$set` operation on an `Id` field, rather than setting the field to an `ObjectId` (which is what I would expect if our custom serializer were being used) the Id gets written out to Mongo DB as a document... as though there were no custom serializer registered at all :-(

I've got some [sample code on GitHub that reproduces the issue](https://github.com/jamescrosswell/MongoTests). If you add a breakpoint at [Line 37 in Program.cs](https://github.com/jamescrosswell/MongoTests/blob/master/MongoTests/Program.cs#L37) you will see that the call to Add (which performs an insert) has run fine (and if you look at the document that was inserted into the tests database at this point, you'll see the Id fields were serialized to `ObjectId`, as expected):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57597589db14c50001d505ad"),
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2016-06-09T13:56:25.088Z"),
    "DateUpdated" : ISODate("2016-06-09T13:56:25.088Z"),
    "SomeProp" : "Foo",
    "IdGuidProp" : "5eec7953-a819-4ce9-8b26-21d86aae1c93",
    "IdProp" : ObjectId("57597589db14c50001d505ae")
}
```

However the next line (#38) blows up... mainly because it isn't able to deserialise the document resulting from the update (`FindOneAndUpdateOptions` includes `ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After`). If you inspect the document in MongoDB at this point, you can see that the custom serializer wasn't used during the `FindOneAndUpdateAsync` operation:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57597589db14c50001d505ad"),
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2016-06-09T13:56:25.088Z"),
    "DateUpdated" : ISODate("2016-06-09T13:56:25.088Z"),
    "SomeProp" : "Bar",
    "IdGuidProp" : {
        "_t" : "Core.IdGuid, Core",
        "_v" : "53062519-4cbf-4464-b972-c7bc6bc7a72d"
    },
    "IdProp" : {
        "_t" : "Core.Id, Core",
        "_v" : ObjectId("57597589db14c50001d505af")
    }
}
```

Is this a bug with the C# driver or is there something I'm missing about custom serializers? Or is there an issue with my code?

Comment: I would imagine the issue is here: https://github.com/jamescrosswell/MongoTests/blob/master/MongoTests/MongoCollectionExtensions.cs#L88. Internally, this ends up on this line (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/FieldDefinition.cs#L338) where _fieldSerializer is null and the resolved serializer doesn't match the type "object", which was used on your line 88 (C# didn't require you to specify it). I believe you'll need to invoke this using reflection to build up your update dynamically. Feel free to file a feature request to add a way for this to work.

Comment: With a breakpoint at [FieldDefinition.cs#L336](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/FieldDefinition.cs#L336) I see `resolvedSerializer = {MongoTests.CustomIdSerializer}`. However `resolvedSerializer as IBsonSerializer<TField>` results in null because `TField` is object. It seems `TField` gets determined when building field definitions at FieldDefinition.cs#L156 as an implicit conversion from string to `FieldDefinition<TDocument, TField>`. I'm not sure why object is used for TField there - possibly because it's the only type the compiler can infer?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's the only type the compiler can infer. You are using reflection, and this API wasn't meant for that. The feature request would be to build in something that can be used with reflection. Perhaps instead of a generic type parameter, and actual parameter of type System.Type.  Until then, you'll probably want to create a FieldDefinition manually using reflection to construct it with the proper generic types.

Comment: @JamesCrosswell Could you summarize your approach on solving this, if you still remember it?